# GPG cache options don't work

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

There is an option named `default-cache-ttl` that controls how long the agent will remember the password to the private key. However, when I put it in the config file it doesn't work - instead, gpg complains:

```
gpg: /home/jan/.gnupg/gpg.conf:8: invalid option
```

My version of GPG is

```
$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong config file. This option concerns `gpg-agent` only, and (somewhat surprisingly) it has a separate configuration file - `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. Put the option there and it works (configuration for GPG 2.1, earlier versions use different option names):

```
$ cat .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
# remember the password longer (1 hour since last usage, 5 hours max)
default-cache-ttl 3600
max-cache-ttl 18000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error after starting `gpg-agent`.
using the following [CLI option](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html) worked (set a cache TTL of 1 month, f.e.):

```
gpg-agent --default-cache-ttl 2629800
```

but I don't know where eventually the value was set.

Comment: I think a config option specified like that is not saved anywhere, it will last only for the duration of that instance of gpg-agent.